# Filter list from the column of another list

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I am trying to do something that I consider complex so far, and is able to filter a listbox, from the column of another list box, with the intention of obtaining data that are not associated.

**Before Filter**

[image: imagen antes de filtrar]

**After Filter**

[image: despues de filtrar]

In the image above, you can see that I selected the Frito Lay mark, and it filters me the list that is in the middle, showing me, only what is related to that mark, but in the list that is next, which is of categories , only one should appear, ayq that of the three registered, only one is not related to any other brand, and is the category or line chocolatinas.

The relationships between the tables is as follows

[image: tablas]

It came to my mind this

```
filas_lista = Me.Lista1.ListCount

    For Fila = 0 To cantidad - 1

        cod_categoria = Me.Lista1.Column(3, Fila)

        consulta = "SELECT Categorias.Id_Categoria_Auto, Categorias.Nombre_Categoria" & _
                   " FROM Categorias" & _
                   " WHERE (((Categorias.Id_Categoria_Auto)<>" & cod_categoria & "))"

        Me.lista_categoria_union.RowSource = consulta
         Me.lista_categoria_union.Requery

    Next Fila
```

Navigate the filtered list, and from there, just leave in the category list those that are not repeated, but only filters by the last item in the list.

Comment: You are cycling the middle listbox? Why not just set the categorias listbox based on the selected marcas? The RowSource SQL can JOIN Categorias and T_Marc_Categoria and filter on Nomb_Marca field. Why do you need categorias listbox? The relevant categories are already in the middle listbox.

Comment: @June7 hi, i need the categories that not are relationship with marca i select, for example, if want it add new categoria for this marca, i need a list with that.

Answer (score 1):

You want categoria not associated with the selected marca, then consider:

```
= "SELECT ID_Categoria_Auto, Nombre_Categoria " & _
"FROM Categorias LEFT JOIN T_Marc_Categ ON Categorias.ID_Categoria_Auto = T_Marc_Categ.ID_Linea " & _
"WHERE ID_Marca<>" & cod_categoria & " OR ID_Marca Is Null;"
```

Comment: I built tables per your model and query definitely works for me - tested in query designer. Although I used input prompt, not reference to a form control. No idea what you mean by 'use two access consulting for obtain the data'.

Comment: I not understand what is `[cod_categoria]`, i talk about, query with a sub-query, [link](https://pastebin.com/dUBmQGtF)

Comment: [cod_categoria] is variable in your code. Sorry, I should not have used [] and need to concatenate. See edited answer.

Comment: However, instead of referencing index 3 in the code, should reference the column that that has ID_Marca which is index 1.